# Android Device Hardware Back Button is not working in ionic4 Apps

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic framework. I have developed a simple app using ionic 4. It is working fine but Android Hardware back button is not working inside ionic app. Please suggest me how can i fix this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution : in homepage.ts

```
 ionViewDidEnter(){ 
  this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{    
  navigator['app'].exitApp(); }); } 

ionViewWillLeave(){ 
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

modifying @Vinod's answer a bit. use `subscribeWithPriority`

```
ionViewDidEnter(){ 
  this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, ()=>{    
    navigator['app'].exitApp(); 
  }); 
} 

ionViewWillLeave() { 
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```